# ExtJS Displaying Panels on Combobox Select

Tags: extjs, combobox, panel, render

Ok, So I have defined 4 panels. Each panel has its own JS file. I call each of them in my main modal window via their alias.

In my application I have this combobox. I want to display the panel depending on the selected item in the combobox.

Here's my code.

Main Modal Window:

```
Ext.define('App1.views.reports.MainReport', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.mainreport',
    title: 'Main Report',
    width: 900,
    autoHeight: true,
    modal: true,
    items: [{
        bodyPadding: 5,
        defaults: {
            border: 0
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Select Report Type',
            id: 'reportType',
            labelWidth: 200,
            width: 320,
            store: reportType,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
        }, {
            //render panel here
        }]
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Done'
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel'
    }]
});
```

Here's the store for my combobox:

```
var reportType = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [
        'name'
    ],
    data: [{
        'name': 'Report1'
    }, {
        'name': 'Report2'
    }, {
        'name': 'Report3'
    }, {
        'name': 'Report4'
    }]
});
```

So once an item is selected in the combobox, a specific panel will appear. Let's say I selected 'Report1', the 'Report 1' panel should appear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [select](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-select) listener to your combobox. You can do the switching of the panels inside the select listener function.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Select Report Type',
    id: 'reportType',
    labelWidth: 200,
    width: 320,
    store: reportType,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, records, eOpts) {
            // put in your logic to switch panel here
        }
    }

}
```

*PS: Not sure which version you are using, the link to the documentation is for extjs 5.0*

Comment: Add *forceSelection: true* if the value can be manually typed.